# How to offset an animation with rotation?

Tags: animation, nla-editor, motion-capture

I made a motion capture with multiple shoot. I used Wonder Dynamics to transfer animation to a character. With Rokoko I retargeted this to a Mixamo character.
I edited some part with NLA, and now I try to offset one of these to match position and rotation.

If I want just translate to X Y or Z position everything fine, but :
If I try to rotate animation, I have some trouble because the rest of animation have some random rotation ...

I try to fix it with an Empty and animation inside (Apply All transforms) but animation is still the same position.

If somebody has an idea, it will be so cool :-)

***-> EDIT :*** I redo a file with Mixamo animation in 2 different directions.

FIRST : On this picture, I selected the animation I want to shift.

[image: On this picture, I selected the animation I want to shift.]

SECOND : Here is the original position of Hips, and good position of animation.

[image: Here the original position of Hips, and good position of animation]

THIRD : Here the shifted position with rotation, and we see animation with error !

[image: Here the shifted position with rotation, and we see animation with error !]

Every snap takes the same frame (37)

[image]

Comment: since you did a lot and also you are using NLA - i would recommend providing blend file because of course we could give general hints but at least it all depends on what you have done. So if you want really a precise answer and not play the "i answer 50 questions in the comments"-game - just provide blend file.

Comment: Generally it's nice to include screenshots - especially GIFs when it's animation. Though admittedly in your case as @Chris noted above, that doesn't beat the .blend file itself . But good to note for future questions ;)

Comment: I edit the post, put some screenshot and file !